# Is it possible to access the entry command bash on a running docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a node docker container on which i'm running a dev server.

In my docker-compose.yml file, the entry command is :

```
...
command: start-dev-server
...
```

Where start-dev-server points to a script that starts the server after a vendor install :

```
// /usr/local/bin/start-dev-server
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# install node modules if missing
npm i
# start the dev server
npm run start
```

So when I start my container, the server will also start.

I know that I can access my container in bash via the following command :

```
docker exec -it my-container bash
```

But there I can't stop or restart my server.
Is there a way to access the ssh with the started command ? (to see the server logs for example, or to stop & restart it).

Maybe I take it by the wrong path here because the entry command isn't supposed to be stopped ? So in this case, would anyone has a solution that could allow me to start my server & control it in a more flexible way ?

Comment: The best practices says that you should see the container as your server. If you want to stop it, stop the container, if you want to restart it, restart the container. Your server should log to `stdout`, so you can see the logs using `docker logs my-container`. So, you're right, the command isn't supposed to be stopped, as it will stop the container. To propose a solution, what do you mean when you say "control it in a more flexible way"?

Comment: Actually the command docker logs -f my-container is totally what I wanted and indeed, to stop and restart the server, I just have to use docker commands. I just missed the -f option for the logs command which allow me to see the logs live ! Thank you sir, you can answer with your comment and I'll accept your answer !

Comment: Thanks! I've added the docker commands and a link to Docker best practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/general-guidelines-and-recommendations) says that you should see the container as your server. If you want to stop it, stop the container (`docker stop my-container`), if you want to restart it, restart the container (`docker restart my-container`). Your server should log to `stdout`, so you can see the logs using `docker logs -f my-container`. So, you're right, the command isn't supposed to be stopped, as it will stop the container.